# 2 Synchronized JScrollPanes inside JSplitPane not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

I have an issue with Swing. I have placed two JScrollPane inside a JSplitPane horizontally and have synchronized the JScrollPanes. Inside each of the JScrollPane I have placed one JPanel. The synchronization i.e. (scrolling a JScrollPane also scrolls the other JScrollPane) between the two JScrollPane works normally. But when I drag the JSplitPane divider towards left/right till some part of a JPanel becomes hidden then horizontal scroll bar is shown but in disabled form. I am not able to scroll to see the hidden part of JPanel.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SplitPaneTest extends JFrame {

    public SplitPaneTest() {

        setTitle( "Splits" );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 400, 400 );

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel1.add( new JLabel( "Left panel!" ) );
        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel1);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel2.add( new JLabel( "Right Panel" ) );
        JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(panel2);

        scrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
        scrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scrollPane1,
                scrollPane2);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        add(splitPane);

        setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SplitPaneTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollbars are displayed automatically when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

You can't share the models because the state of each scrollbar will be different depending on how much space is allocation to each scroll pane. The only time they will be in sync is when the divider of the split pane is in the middle.

So you need to listen for changes in the scrollbar of each scroll pane and than attempt to adjust the scrollbar from the other scroll pane.

Something like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SplitPaneTest2 extends JFrame {

    public SplitPaneTest2() {

        setTitle( "Splits" );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 400, 400 );

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel1.add( new JLabel( "Left panel!11111111111111111111" ) );
        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel1);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel2.add( new JLabel( "Right Panel11111111111111111111" ) );
        JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(panel2);

//        scrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
//        scrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());
        new ScrollBarSynchronizer(scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar(), scrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar());

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scrollPane1,
                scrollPane2);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        add(splitPane);

        setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SplitPaneTest2();
    }

    static class ScrollBarSynchronizer implements AdjustmentListener
    {
        JScrollBar[] scrollBars;

        public ScrollBarSynchronizer(JScrollBar... scrollBars)
        {
            this.scrollBars = scrollBars;

            for (JScrollBar scrollBar: scrollBars)
                scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener( this );
        }

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
        {
            JScrollBar source = (JScrollBar)e.getSource();
            int value = e.getValue();

            for (JScrollBar scrollBar: scrollBars)
            {
                if (scrollBar != source)
                {
                    scrollBar.removeAdjustmentListener( this );
                    scrollBar.setValue( value );
                    scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener( this );
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can also create a separate synchronizer for the vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks @camickr for saving my days. Wow that's fantastic. Your code is working perfectly as per my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the point is that **shifting the divider of the JSplitPane does not RESIZE the JScrollPane**. Nevertheless the VIEW on the JScrollPane is changed therefore the scrollbar is shown by the JScrollPane (*The scrollbar automatically appears when the preferred size of a component is greater than the size of the viewport on the JPanel in the JScrollPane*)
But the scrollbar it is greyed-out because from the viewpoint of the JScrollPane there is no need to scroll (the JPanel it contains was not resized and therefore does not exceed the size of the JScrollPane...)

**UPDATE** this works for me, the solution is to put as much content in the JPanels that the scrollbars appear (the font is a bit shredded when scrolled fast)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SplitPaneTest extends JFrame {

    public SplitPaneTest() {

        setTitle( "Splits" );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 200, 200 );

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //panel1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //panel1.revalidate();            
        panel1.add( new JLabel( "Left panel! fhajsdfasbkfbbsdkjafbkajhbshabshjdfbajsbskjaSK" ) );



        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel1,  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        //scrollPane1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //scrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //scrollPane1.revalidate();

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //panel2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //panel2.revalidate();

        panel2.add( new JLabel( "Right Panel dfgasdgsdghsgs<dg<sdgs<dgdsgdfsafasfasfasfsafa" ) );
        JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(panel2, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        //scrollPane2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //scrollPane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        //scrollPane2.revalidate();

        scrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
        scrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scrollPane1,
                scrollPane2);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        //splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
        this.add(splitPane);

        this.setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SplitPaneTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: scrollPaneCreating.getViewport().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(160, 200)); is making the JSplitPane divider not resizable.

Comment: I want the JScrollPanes to appear when needed. Setting the minimum size on JScrollPane not allowing me to resize JSplitPane divider. 
So I did this: 
scrollPane1.getViewport().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(160, 200)); scrollPane2 .getViewport().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(160, 200));
Still no luck. After resizing JSplitPane divider, the scroll pane not getting enabled to show its hidden content.

Comment: Don't play with the sizes (preferred, minimum, maximum). A component should be responsible for knowing its own size and should change dynamically as the properties of the component changes.

Comment: the setPreferredSize() variant is mentioned in several other threads here therefore i tried it and it also works...

Comment: The problem was with below code snippet:
scrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
        scrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());

Comment: Usually that is standard way to synchronize scrolling of two JScrollPane. But something is going wrong with that kind of synchronization inside JSplitPane. I tried all ways suggested by you but no luck.

Code by @camickr as shown below has solved the issue now.

Comment: Thanks @ralf htp for your help and insights.

Comment: (1-) The setPreferredSize() method might appear to work in a simple example. It will not be a robust solution in the real world. Hardcoding random values is not how Swing was designed to work. The preferred size is meant to be dynamic as properties of the component change. The size of the scrollbar is determined by the preferred size. Using this method indicates you do not understand the basics of how a Swing scroll pane works. Using a random number will either 1) not scroll completely or 2) scroll even when there is no data.

Comment: yes, that is correct. setPreferredSize() is not the best solution but it is a solution. maybe i remove it from the answer